# Monthly active device installs in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play

For each app, Google Play Developer shows a daily number of active device installs. Therefore, if we consider the value for two days, the most of the devices will be included in the two sets because those devices will be active both of the days.

However, I'd like to know how many active devices there are in a month. I could calculate the average of the number of active device installs for each day of the month but it doesn't reflect how many unique active devices have the app installed in one month because many devices are active each day.

Is there any way to get the number of unique active device installs by month instead of by day?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Active device installs doesn't mean active that day. It means active at some point in the last 30 days. See this [help center article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?ref_topic=6299716), in the "Metrics", "Install related statistics" section.

> Installs on active devices:   Number of Android devices that have been online at least once in the past 30 days that have your app installed.